# SQL query to get appended resultset from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables  , with a column name 'mobile number' in both of them. I need the result set of all distinct 'mobile number' from both the tables. What would be my query for the same.

p.s : This is my first question and i am new to sql query as well. Apologies for any silly assumptions if any.

Comment: You have some query that you tried ?

Comment: [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) will do the trick!

Comment: Learn something about `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union` on selection from both tables.

```
select mobile_number from table_1
union
select mobile_number from table_2
```

Using `Union` eliminates all duplicate results and present only *distinct* values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
select distinct(mobilenumber)
from table
union
select distinct(mobilenumber)
from table1;
```